# How can I get timezone from province or state in typescript (frontend)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, timezone

I have an angular application in which the user can select a country and state/province. I need to figure out the timezone based on the state/province (we're currently only focused on Canada and the US; later, we will focus on other countries). The user's selection contains both the full description of the state/province and the two letter abbreviation. I'm looking for an NPM package or some other kind of javascript library that I can feed the province/state into and get the timezone back.

Something like this looks like it might work:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/city-timezones

...but it's a node package. I need something for frontend typescript. Is there anything available?

Comment: I don't think this would be a good approach - too many US (13) states have more than one time zone. Also, DST is really going to never be right and practically doubles each state's time zones.

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue to use an npm package, whereas node_modules we are adding in Angular application, are all from npm packages. Although you are using angular application and TypeScript you should make a try with the package you mentioned at first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`city-timezones`](https://github.com/kevinroberts/city-timezones#readme) to create a lookup table for timezone by country and province, for example:

```html
<script type="module">
  import cityTimezones from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/city-timezones';
  
  function groupTimezones(country, arr) {
    const countryData = arr.filter(city => city.country === country && city.timezone && city.province);
    const sortedByProvince = countryData.sort((a,b) => a.province.localeCompare(b.province));
    return sortedByProvince.reduce((acc, city) => { 
        const key = city.province;
        acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
        if (!acc[key].includes(city.timezone)) {
            acc[key].push(city.timezone);
        }
        return acc;
    }, {})
}

console.log('Canada:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(groupTimezones('Canada', cityTimezones.cityMapping), null, 4));
console.log('United States:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(groupTimezones('United States of America', cityTimezones.cityMapping), null, 4));


</script>
```

This outputs a list of timezones for each province in Canada and the United States.

You could use this data for your frontend. If there's only one timezone per province no input from the user is required.

If there is more than one, you could prompt the user for the most appropriate one, or select the most likely timezone for each province, perhaps replacing the IANA timezone names with the more commonly used alternative names 'Central Time', 'Eastern Time' etc. in the UI.

We can use [`tzdb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vvo/tzdb) to find the alternative name for each IANA zone below:

```html
<script type="module">
import cityTimezones from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/city-timezones';
import { getTimeZones, rawTimeZones, timeZonesNames } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@vvo/tzdb';

const timeZones = getTimeZones();

function groupTimezones(country, arr) {
    const countryData = arr.filter(city => city.country === country && city.timezone && city.province);
    const sortedByProvince = countryData.sort((a,b) => a.province.localeCompare(b.province));
    return sortedByProvince.reduce((acc, city) => {
        // Get the alternative name, e.g. Eastern time
        const altTz = (timeZones.find(t => t.name === city.timezone || t.group.includes(city.timezone)) || []).alternativeName || 'NotFound - ' + city.timezone;
        const key = city.province;
        acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
        if (!acc[key].includes(altTz)) {
            acc[key].push(altTz)
        }
        return acc;
    }, {})
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(groupTimezones('Canada', cityTimezones.cityMapping), null, 4));
console.log(JSON.stringify(groupTimezones('United States of America', cityTimezones.cityMapping), null, 4));

</script>
```

We still have the problem that some states / provinces have multiple timezones, however you can skip asking the user for most provinces since they will only have one zone.

If a province has multiple zones you could simply ask the user which one to use, for example if they select British Columbia you could ask whether to use Mountain Time, Pacific Time or Yukon Time.